# Create A Record of @ and WWW

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, a-record

I have a VIRB website I want to link-up and it tells me I have to use this for help: http://virb.com/docs/domain

Easy, enough. I got into my cPanel where my domain is hosted and go to DNS Zone Editor. Tells me I need to point "@" and "www" to *64.207.128.132*... but I cannot see where to do that.

**However** - Everytime I type "@" or "www" into the box to "Add an A Record"... it AUTOMATICALLY fills it with the suffix of my domain so.. @.MYDOMAIN.COM,. (yes, with the period) I cannot get rid of that suffix. Argh

Help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ is [BIND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bind9) configuration directive equivalent to the base domain (e.g. domain.tld).

You should set the A record for domain.tld to 64.207.128.132 .

Comment: OK I added `mydomain.com`.. appearently it adds the period at the end of the name... weird. But I got it set-up.

Comment: @weka That's not particularly odd. It's a way of declaring that it's a child of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_domain .

Comment: Ah, okay. I got it. So I got it done, should take a while to propagate right?

Comment: @weka Depends on the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records of your records and how well TTL is honored by various caching name servers. You can always query your actual NS servers to see if it should be propagating. `dig domain.tld +trace` is good for that, if you have access to `dig`. Else you'll have to lookup your nameserver `nslookup -q=ns domain.tld`, then lookup against those `nslookup domain.tld <nameserver from previous query>`

Comment: It seems like it's still stuck on the OLD DNS..even though GoDaddy has the new ones. I guess I just have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix is not a problem.  Records are being created for the fully-qualified domain name.. which is exactly what you intended to do, right?

Comment: Yes but it won't let me create `@.MYDOMAIN.COM.` and `www.MYDOMAIN.COM.` A Record is already a CNAME...

Comment: @weka Leave the name blank and it might let you enter a record that's effectively `@`.  I'm not seeing a `CNAME` for `www`, but you'll need to remove that if you want an `A` record for `www`.

Comment: I was able to go into Advanced DNS Editor... and delete the `www.mydomain.com.` CNAME record and create a new A Record based of that. Hopefully it worked. Should take a while to propagate right?

Comment: @weka Most DNS recursive resolvers and some clients will cache lookup data, but you should be able to verify that everything's working well by querying the authoritative server directly.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @weka `dig @name-server-that-your-domain-uses www.example.com`

Comment: `'dig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Windows, then.  `nslookup www.example.com name-server-that-your-domain-uses`.